# To which particles does the inflaton field preferably couple?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I am studying the (p)reheating dynamics and I would like to know if it is a reasonable assumption to consider a generic inflaton field (not the Higgs-inflaton) to be coupled with the same intensity to every degree of freedom of the standard model, and eventually also to heavy sterile neutrinos; or if there are instead strong reasons to consider the inflaton coupling to some species (or types of particles, i.e. fermions or bosons) privileged with respect to others.

Did anybody study this precise topic of the coupling of the inflaton to the other fields in a systematic way before?

Could someone suggest any references on that to me?

Comment: Have you tried googling? "inflaton coupling arxiv" .   ?  also "nflaton coupling to fermions  arxiv "